# WP Redirect with user nickname/username

Tags: php

I am trying to redirect the user after login/signup to profile page, but I am not sure why is it not putting the user nickname in url.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

function aloginuser( $user_id ) {
    wp_set_current_user($user_id);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_id);
    wp_redirect( "/profile/$current_user->user_login" );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'aloginuser' );
```

It need to put site.com/profile/username

Comment: What happens if you add `$current_user = wp_get_current_user();`  after the `wp_set_auth_cookie` call?

Comment: I think you should use `wp_login` hook. And looks like `$current_user` is out of scope inside your function.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a header() function instead of wp_redirect, so

```
header("Location: mysite.com/profile/username");
```

Comment: Please explain why that would solve the problem. I cannot see any improvement over the existing code.

Comment: Yes! How it will solve the problem? Please explain?

Comment: It will not add  currently logged username in url

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
function redirect_user ($user_login, $user) {
    wp_redirect( "/profile/" .$user_login );// $user_login is $user->user_login
    exit;
}
add_action('wp_login', 'redirect_user', 10, 2);
```